# How to create a softlink for a device in centos7

Tags: centos7

I have a CentOS7.0 VM with virtio disk that has multiple partitions.
These disk partitions are named as vda1, vda2, vda3 etc by default.
But, I want to name them as sda1, sda2 etc as the application that 
i am running on it expect the partition name start with sda.

I have tried to chage the rules for virtio-blk in
/lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage.rules from

```
# virtio-blk
KERNEL=="vd*[!0-9]", ATTRS{serial}=="?*", ENV{ID_SERIAL}="$attr{serial}", SYMLINK+="disk/by-id/virtio-$env{ID_SERIAL}"
KERNEL=="vd*[0-9]", ATTRS{serial}=="?*", ENV{ID_SERIAL}="$attr{serial}", SYMLINK+="disk/by-id/virtio-$env{ID_SERIAL}-part%n"
```

to

```
# virtio-blk
KERNEL=="sd*[!0-9]", ATTRS{serial}=="?*", ENV{ID_SERIAL}="$attr{serial}", SYMLINK+="disk/by-id/virtio-$env{ID_SERIAL}"
KERNEL=="sd*[0-9]", ATTRS{serial}=="?*", ENV{ID_SERIAL}="$attr{serial}", SYMLINK+="disk/by-id/virtio-$env{ID_SERIAL}-part%n"
```

But, I still see the partition name starts with vda.
Hence, I am trying to create a symlink for the vda device.
I am not sure how to write a udev rule to create the following
symlinks.

```
sda1 -> vda1
sda2 -> vda2
sda3 -> vda3
```

Could anyone please let me know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
$ ln -s vda1 sda1
$ ln -s vda2 sda2
$ ln -s vda3 sda3
```

should do it, assuming you're in the directory where the vdan's are.